# Slick Slider not initializing as it should

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I'm trying to create a sample of Slick Slider but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <title>Slick Playground</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-master/slick/slick.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="slick-master/slick/slick-theme.css">
</head>
<body>

<section class="regular">
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=1">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=2">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=3">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=4">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=5">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x300?text=6">
    </div>
</section>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="slick-master/slick/slick.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('ready', function() {
        $(".regular").slick({
            dots: true,
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
```

And this is the what the browser is [showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnMne.png), but it was suppose to be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dzu9.png).

Can someone explain me how am I suppose to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's taking the full width of the browser because the `section` tag's default is 100% width. Slick slider is then adjusting the width of the `div` tags to fill the space. Try setting a small width on the `section` tag in your CSS